# function to calculate best profit of array of stocks and time

Tags: python

i'm writing function that gets an array of stock prices and calculates the best buy and sale profit.
Each value in the array is the stock price and the index number is the hour of the price.
how can keep indexes of the prices i want to buy and sell?

```
def inputValidation(price):
    isValidPrice = False
    # Validate input type is a number
    if isinstance(price, int) or isinstance(price, float):
        # Validate number > 0
        if price < 0:
            isValidPrice = False
        else:
            isValidPrice = True
    return isValidPrice


def arraySizeValidation(arr):
    if 2 < len(arr) < 24:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def stockManagement(arr):
    potentialProfit = 0
    maxProfitValue = 0
    currentMaxValue = 0
    minIndex = 0
    maxIndex = len(arr)
    tempArr = arr
    if arraySizeValidation(arr):
        for price in reversed(arr):

            # Validates input
            if inputValidation(price):
                print("current max:", currentMaxValue)
                print("price:", price)

                currentMaxValue = max(currentMaxValue, price)
                potentialProfit = currentMaxValue - price
                minIndex = arr.index(price)
                maxIndex = arr.index(currentMaxValue)

                print("potential_profit:", potentialProfit)

                maxProfitValue = max(potentialProfit, maxProfitValue)


                print("maxProfitValue:", maxProfitValue)
                print("-------------")
                print("\n")
            else:
                print("Array size not valid")
    

arr1 = [97,101,2,99,3,25,37]
arr2 = [13, 15, 7, "s", "s", 25, 37]
hours = ["12:00 AM", "01:00 AM", "02:00 AM", "03:00 AM", "04:00 AM", "05:00 AM", "06:00 AM", "07:00 AM",
         "08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "13:00 PM", "14:00 PM", "15:00 PM", "16:00 PM",
         "17:00 PM", "18:00 PM", "19:00 PM", "20:00 PM", "21:00 PM", "22:00 PM", "23:00 PM"]

stockManagement(arr1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *'keep indexes of the prices i want to buy and sell'* ?

Comment: i mean the indexes of the values i use to calculate the profit

Comment: `minIndex` and `maxIndex` ? Where do you want to keep them ?

Comment: i want to print them at the end of the function.

Comment: i need to print the indexes of the values i use to calculate the final best profit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you save the price and its indexes in a list, then return it at the end:

```
def stockManagement(arr):
    maxProfitValue = 0
    currentMaxValue = 0
    
    # The list that will be returned at the end
    index_list = []

    minIndex = 0
    maxIndex = len(arr)
    for price in reversed(arr):
        # Validates input
        if inputValidation(price):

            print("current max:", currentMaxValue)
            print("price:", price)

            currentMaxValue = max(currentMaxValue, price)
            potentialProfit = currentMaxValue - price
            minIndex = arr.index(price)
            maxIndex = arr.index(currentMaxValue)

            if maxProfitValue > potentialProfit:
                minIndex = arr.index(price)
                maxIndex = arr.index(currentMaxValue)
                print(minIndex)
                print(maxIndex)

            print("potential_profit:",potentialProfit)

            maxProfitValue = max(potentialProfit, maxProfitValue)
            
            # We add to the list a nested list that contains the price and its indexes
            index_list.append([price, minIndex, maxIndex])

            print("maxProfitValue:", maxProfitValue)
            print("-------------")
            print("\n")
    print(minIndex)
    print(maxIndex)
    print(maxProfitValue)
    
    # We return the result
    return index_list



def inputValidation(price):
    isValidPrice = False
    if isinstance(price,int) or isinstance(price,float):
        isValidPrice = True
    return isValidPrice



arr1 = [101,15,2,99,3,25,37]
arr2 = [13,15,7,"s","s",25,37]

# Do whatever you want with the indexes
print(stockManagement(arr1))
```

Output:

```
[[37, 6, 6], [25, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6], [99, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3], [15, 1, 3], [101, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: this is not helping me, i need only to profit with the indexes of the values it uses to be calculated